# Is there a way to Check if something is written except waiting till something is written with "Console.ReadLine()"

Tags: c#

I'm doing a TCP Messenger Programm ATM with TCPClient and TCPListener. Everything is working fine. I've had both of these in separate programs and now I'm basically trying to make it one Program. I'm stuck with the fact that it is always WAITING till I have something written to send it before it goes to checking the receive. I'm new to C# and learning. So I need a way to check "is something written? If no, then skip this" basically a bool to ask if something is written.

I've tried to make it like "if the line in storage right now is the same as the was the last time, skip it" so it doesnt stuck infinitly in the Send sector of the program. But still it ALWAYS waits until I wrote something before it even checks/ skips it.

This is the write and send loop code:

```
nachricht = Console.ReadLine();
if (nachrichtcheck != nachricht)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test1");
    TcpClient clientnachricht = new TcpClient(zielip, port);
    NetworkStream streamnachricht = clientnachricht.GetStream();

    sendnachricht = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(nachricht);

    streamnachricht.Write(sendnachricht, 0, sendnachricht.Length);

    streamnachricht.Close();
    clientnachricht.Close();
    nachrichtcheck = nachricht;
    Console.WriteLine("test2");
}
else
{
    if (empfangstream.CanRead)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test3");
        byte[] receivedBuffer2 = new byte[100];
        NetworkStream stream = empfangclient.GetStream();

        stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

        StringBuilder msg2 = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte b in receivedBuffer)
        {
            if (b.Equals(00))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
                msg2.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("test4");
        empfangscheck2 = msg2.ToString();
        if (empfangscheck2 != empfangscheck)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg2.ToString());
            empfangscheck = msg2.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("receive");
        }
    }
}
```

So if someone can help me just getting a way to get a bool to check if something is written -> then use it. Except of wait until something is written -> use it it would help me miles.

Comment: Console.KeyAvailable?

Comment: I haven't tried, but in addition to @Joe's excellent suggestion, I suppose one could probably do the console read on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an alternative to solve your problem. You can use a thread to wait for an user input instead of your actual code.

---

(I've also considered your german language)
Code Example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string nachricht = "";
            double AndereTätigkeitBeweis = 0;
        Thread NachrichtenEinleser = new Thread(()=> {
            Console.Write("Gib diene zu sendende Nachricht ein: ");//Type in the message you'd like to send
            nachricht = Console.ReadLine();//Read the user Input without stopping the actual code because it's another process
        });

        NachrichtenEinleser.Start();

        //do somewhat activity until you get a user input
        while (nachricht == ""){
            AndereTätigkeitBeweis++;
        }

        //Write out the user input
        Console.WriteLine($"User Input: {nachricht}|AndereTätigkeitBeweis: {AndereTätigkeitBeweis}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

---

> Output example:
>   Gib diene zu sendende Nachricht ein: hallo
>   User Input: hallo|AndereTätigkeitBeweis: 560075647
>
> ---
>
> Hope this helps.